# Seeking open source alternative to ESRI operations dashboard

Tags: gis, dashboard

My company is planning to shift the complete GIS stack from ESRI to open source.
i.e.  from:

- ArcGIS, ArcGIS Server, MSSQL SRVR (sde), ArcGIS JS API

to:

- QGIS, GeoServer, PostGIS, OpenLayers/Leaflet.

The only thing that is lacking from this stack is an alternative to operational dashboard. i.e. an easy to use dashboard creation platform - usable by the management.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please **[edit]** your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: what features do you need? What OS should it run on? How much you'd be willing to spend if it comes to paid solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Creating Dashboard Styled Map Layout with QGIS
https://gwisnu.medium.com/creating-dashboard-styled-map-layout-with-qgis-de19211d223e

Video on Leaflet https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ok-VbW7wBEg&ab_channel=GIS%26ITTools

Additionally, try Mapstore2, for more of a Dashboard based solution which may suit.
https://mapstore2.readthedocs.io/en/user_docs/

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. I am already familiar with leaflet, numpy and many other charts libraries to develop a custom dashboard. But I was looking for something like operations dashboard that does not need major development rather just drag and drop hence "usable by the management" (like I mentioned in the question).
Is there any other GIS forum that you recommend?

Comment: Mapstore2 is more like a GUI driven solution that 'managers' may be able to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try apache superset. Opensource and docker instalation quick and easy.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/64515)

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Your answer has been flag as low quality and might be removed; please have a look at [What is required for an answer to be high quality?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/356/23377) for some tips on how to improve it.